# How to add "one-to" part of "one-to-many" to fetch results

Tags: swift, core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchrequest

I want to be able to add the player's data the "to-one" part of the many relationships.  The fetch does some aggregation for me, but I would like to know what `player` it belongs to.

I have a CoreData model that looks like the following:

[image]

I have a fetch request that looks like the following:

```
func statsPerPlayer(player: Players, managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext)  -> [String: Int] {

    var resultsDic = [String: Int]()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Shifts")
    let predicate               = NSPredicate(format: "playersRelationship = %@", player)
    fetchRequest.predicate      = predicate

    let nsExpressionForKeyPath  = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "timeOnIce")

    let nsExpressionForFunctionMin = NSExpression(forFunction: "min:", arguments: [nsExpressionForKeyPath])
    let nsExpressionDescriptionMin = NSExpressionDescription()
    nsExpressionDescriptionMin.expression = nsExpressionForFunctionMin
    nsExpressionDescriptionMin.name = "minShift"
    nsExpressionDescriptionMin.expressionResultType = .integer16AttributeType

    let nsExpressionForFunctionMax = NSExpression(forFunction: "max:", arguments: [nsExpressionForKeyPath])
    let nsExpressionDescriptionMax = NSExpressionDescription()
    nsExpressionDescriptionMax.expression = nsExpressionForFunctionMax
    nsExpressionDescriptionMax.name = "maxShift"
    nsExpressionDescriptionMax.expressionResultType = .integer16AttributeType

    let nsExpressionForFunctionSum = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [nsExpressionForKeyPath])
    let nsExpressionDescriptionSum = NSExpressionDescription()
    nsExpressionDescriptionSum.expression = nsExpressionForFunctionSum
    nsExpressionDescriptionSum.name = "sumShift"
    nsExpressionDescriptionSum.expressionResultType = .integer16AttributeType

    let nsExpressionForFunctionAvg = NSExpression(forFunction: "average:", arguments: [nsExpressionForKeyPath])
    let nsExpressionDescriptionAvg = NSExpressionDescription()
    nsExpressionDescriptionAvg.expression = nsExpressionForFunctionAvg
    nsExpressionDescriptionAvg.name = "avgShift"
    nsExpressionDescriptionAvg.expressionResultType = .integer16AttributeType

    let nsExpressionForFunctionCount = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [nsExpressionForKeyPath])
    let nsExpressionDescriptionCount = NSExpressionDescription()
    nsExpressionDescriptionCount.expression = nsExpressionForFunctionCount
    nsExpressionDescriptionCount.name = "countShift"
    nsExpressionDescriptionCount.expressionResultType = .integer16AttributeType

    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch   = [nsExpressionDescriptionMin, nsExpressionDescriptionMax, nsExpressionDescriptionSum, nsExpressionDescriptionAvg, nsExpressionDescriptionCount]

    fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

    do {

        let fetchArray = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print(fetchArray)
        resultsDic = fetchArray.first as! [String : Int]

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print("\(self) -> \(#function): Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    return resultsDic

}  //statsPerPlayer
```

The results look great and something like this:

```
[{
    avgShift = 39;
    countShift = 4;
    maxShift = 89;
    minShift = 6;
    sumShift = 157;
}]
```

However, I would like to include the `player` that this data is for.  How do I add the `"to-one"` part of the `one-to-many` relationship in the results?

Thanks!!

Comment: What happens if you just add “playersRelationship” to the array of propertiesToFetch?

Comment: If I add `player.playersShiftRelationship!` I get `unrecognized selector sent to instance`  If I add `shifts.playersRelationship!` I get the same error.

Comment: You are fetching Shifts, so you need to specify the name of the relationship on the Shifts entity, ie "playersRelationship".

Comment: I think I do as you suggest:          `let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Shifts", in: managedContext)
        let shifts = Shifts(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above, just add the relevant relationship name to the properties to fetch:

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch   = ["playersRelationship", nsExpressionDescriptionMin, nsExpressionDescriptionMax, nsExpressionDescriptionSum, nsExpressionDescriptionAvg, nsExpressionDescriptionCount]
```

The dictionaries that are returned will then include the key "playersRelationship" with value set to the `NSManagedObjectID` of the corresponding `Players` object.  You can then use the context's `object(with:)` method to access the `Players` object itself.

**Update**

So after some testing, it turns out:

a) CoreData gets confused regarding the `count` aggregate function if you include the relationship in the propertiesToFetch.  That leads to the `Invalid keypath (request for aggregate operation on a toOne-only keypath` error.

b) CoreData gets confused for all the other aggregate functions if you include the relationship in the propertiesToFetch.  (It calculates the aggregate across every object, not just those matching the predicate.)

The solution to both problems is to add the relationship as a GROUP BY property.  CoreData then calculates the aggregates correctly and also correctly recognises `count` as a valid operation.  So, add the following line:

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy   = ["playersRelationship"]
```

Comment: I get the following error: `[error] error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x60000018ec70> , Invalid keypath (request for aggregate operation on a toOne-only keypath): timeOnIce with userInfo of (null)`

Comment: @PaulS. I can't see why that would be; can you edit your original post with your current code and error(s).

Comment: The current code is exactly as posted, and same for error.

Comment: @ pbasdf Great work, thanks.  That's probably the only combination I didn't try.  Do you know of a quick way to run the above through all my `Players` without having so another `Players` fetch and then a for in loop?

Comment: Just drop the predicate - the returned array will then have one dictionary for each player.

Comment: One last question.  The fetch works great now.  Thanks for that.  When I use the following in a TableView: `let player = playerStatsArray[indexPath.row]` `let playerDetails = player["playersRelationship"] as! Players` I get the following error: `Could not cast value of type '_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID' (0x1088051f8) to 'Time_on_Ice.Players' (0x107236b88).`

Comment: My return results are: `["avgShift": 39, "minShift": 6, "sumShift": 157, "playersRelationship": 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://615F1345-3ACE-4F8F-BE0A-3C1832A50EE6/Players/p2>, "countShift": 4, "maxShift": 89]`

Comment: It's worth nothing that player = [String: Any]

Comment: Insert `let playerObjID = player[“playersRelationship”] as! NSManagedObjectID   let playerDetails = managedContext.object(with: playerObjID)`

Comment: you had already mentioned this, my apologies, I missed it.  Thanks again.  I had to add `as! Players` to `let playerDetails = managedContext.object(with: playerObjID)` now everything rocks!!

Comment: One last question.  How would I add a count for the `gameRelationship`  I don't want the actual relationship information, just the count? `numberOfGames = 2` for example.  When I add another NSExpression to `count` #keyPath(Shifts.gameRelationship) it just returns the relationship, I just need a count of `gameRelationship`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162263/discussion-between-pbasdf-and-paul-s).